# Grid Splitter problem in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, gridsplitter

I want a layout like VS 2008. In which I want two columns and second columns is again split into two.

I done that in the xaml mentioned below, but the `GridSplitter` is not visible vertically ( which split two columns).

I want both the `GridSplitter`s to be resizable. One `GridSplitter` resizes the Left Hand Pane and Right Hand Pane and another `GridSplitter` resizes the subgrid's top pane and right pane..

The Second `GridSplitter` is working through this XAML but I am not able to produce XAML code that Splits the Right hand Pane and Left hand pane..
Pleas Help!!

```
<Window x:Class="AlarmUI_2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Grid.Column="0" >
            <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap">Left Hand Side</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" ResizeDirection="Auto" 
                      Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
                <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Background="Gray"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Background="Violet" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change your vertical Splitter to

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="5" ResizeDirection="Auto" 
            Grid.RowSpan="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

This will be much better way to use GridSplitter

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Grid.Column="0" >
        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap">Left Hand Side</TextBlock>


    </StackPanel>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
            <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Background="Violet">
            <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So far, this is the only way that hasn't broken within 4 minutes. Great answer.

Comment: Great answer! Sometimes a good (and working!) example is better than 100 Explanations!

Answer (score 2):

The GridSplitters should probably be on their own row/column in the grid, not sharing a cell with the other controls.

Answer (score 2):

Your gridsplitter is behind the other controls that's why you can't see it. You can either move it to the bottom in your XAML file (so it is added last) or use the [Panel.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) attached property. Additionally you have to set the width for the splitter correctly correctly:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Grid.Column="0" >
        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap">Left Hand Side</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
            <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Background="Gray"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Background="Violet" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" ResizeDirection="Columns" 
            Grid.RowSpan="1" Width="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have acheived the functionality, the XAML is mentioned below:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Grid.Column="0" >
        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap">Left Hand Side</TextBlock>


    </StackPanel>


    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" ResizeDirection="Columns"  Width="5" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>




    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Background="Gray"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Background="Violet" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>World</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If anybody know better approach to acheive the same layout then do post your answers. I want to achieve Outlook layout