# C# WPF : Grid splitter not expanding grid above it

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

I've placed a grid splitter between a  grid and a textbox and treeview. The grid has a context menu associated with it. When I use the grid splitter, sometimes there is a huge gap between the splitter and the contents of the grid and in this empty space, the context menu doesn't show up. 
Any idea how to make this happen? How do I get the grid to expand.
Also, just out of curiosity, what does the splitter fill this empty space with?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="400"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row ="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="400">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="BluhBluh"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock>BluhBluh</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row ="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="200">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="BluhBluh"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock>BluhBluh</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Add some code and an image of what it is know and what you want

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to know and confusing what you have right now and what you want to achieve.
Anyways, try to check this question([Grid Splitter problem in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748168/grid-splitter-problem-in-wpf?rq=1)) and the best answer on the thread will give you a better way to implement and use grid splitter. :)